# Using the present tense for future event?

Tags: grammar, tense

I am not sure if we can use the present for future events. I know we can use the historical present for past event, but I am not sure if we can use the present for future events.

Here's an example sentence where the present is used for future events:

> You should ask God "What is the meaning of life" when he **judges** your
>   soul.

Is judges being in the present tense ok in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

> You should ask God "What is the meaning of life" when he judges your soul.

is a perfectly valid sentence.Indeed i don't see an obvious way to rewrite it in a future tense.

The Wikipedia article on [Future tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense#English) points out that  "present tense with future meaning" is a common usage, and gives as examples:

> - The train leaves at five.
> - My cousins arrive tomorrow.

Both are in the present in strict grammatical form, both obviously refer tpo future events, and both are perfectly natural and correct sentences.

The Wikipedia article also points out that:

> Use of the present tense (rather than forms with will) is mandatory in some subordinate clauses referring to the future, such as "If I feel better next week..." and "As soon as they arrive, ...".

and I fully agree.